# EF Context.Set<T>() Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get data with a condition as lambda expression like in.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetBy(Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        var test = Context.Set<StateInfo>().Where(p => p.CustomerID != null && p.CustomerID == 5);

        var test2= Context.Set<T>().Where(condition);
               .
               .
    }
```

When I am looking the test object SQL query It use where clause in It. But the test2 object query is like only select * from table. It gets all data from DB then use when method in code side. How can I get data with where clause because test2 query takes a long time with big datas. Only difference is one of the codes with generic class but the sql queries different. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is type of `Func<T, bool>`. When you look at overload of `context.Set<T>().Where()` you can see that, the one which takes `Func<T, bool>` returns `IEnumerable<T>` instaead of `IQuerable<T>`, because it takes all the data from the source, *then* applies filter. You should use `Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition`. Your method should be something like:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
    where T : class
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Where(condition);               
}
```

**Note:** If you want to return IEnumerable after filtering you can just keep it like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
    where T : class
{
    // Should also work without AsEnumerable()
    return Context.Set<T>().Where(condition).AsEnumerable();               
}
```

Comment: Idk but I tried it before like `Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(condition)`. Without AsQueryable() now It works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Brucay, no need to use `AsQueryable()` on `Set<T>()` When you call `Where(condition)` with `Func<T, bool>` predicate, this overload method internally gets all the data as enumerable then apllies filter.

Comment: `Context.Set<T>().Where(condition).AsEnumerable();` I changed my code like that but It gives error:

Non-Public members = error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SafranOffice.ORM.CandidateInfo>'

Comment: @Burcay, how do you call the method?

Comment: `resultCandidate = _repo.GetBy(p => resultStateInfo.Select(s => s.MemberID).Contains(p.CandidateMemberID)).ToList();
`

Comment: @Burcay, but you have to provide type to `GetBy` method. Like: `SomeType s = GetBy<SomeType>(m => m.SomeProperty = someValue)`. It is a generic method, and it should not compile when you do not provide type. Because there is nothing it can be infered from.

Comment: @AdilMammadov Well `T` could be in the class definition, not method, it would explain how OPs code compiles.

Comment: @DavidG, you are right, it can be. But, I do not think that it is the case here. look at provided error message, I am afraid T is created as a type? Or am I missing something.

Comment: _repo is also inherited from repositorybase and 
provided by `public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class`

Comment: It works now I changed the resultStateInfo to List from IList. Any solution without change it type? @adilmammadov

Comment: @Burcay, I am sorry, I cannot help further, because I do not know much about your repository, resultStateInfo or anything else. May be I am wrong, but the problem should not be related to IList or List.

Comment: But it worked. Can we discuss this anywhere else @adilmammadov ?

Comment: It should have already prompted to move this discussion to chat. I will try to move it to chat

Comment: @adilmammadov how can I contact with you?

Comment: @Burcay, my email address is mammadov.adil@outlook.com

Answer (score 1):

Use `Expression` instead.

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition
```

When you use `Func` it cant be trunslated to SQL. You get the whole data the filter them inmemory.
In case of `Expression` it will transleared to SQL and you will get filtered data from SQL server.

Comment: Idk but I tried it before like `Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(condition)`. Without AsQueryable() now It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked a long time ago, but it was relevant to me now and in search of a solution I did it

```
 public class Command<T> : IRepository<T>
 {
     public Context Context; 

     private IQueryable<T>? Reflection()
     {
         MethodInfo method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Set", new Type[] { });
         MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
         IQueryable<T>? queryable = ((IQueryable<T>)generic.Invoke(Context, null));
         return queryable;
     }
     public IEnumerable<T> Where(Func<T, bool> Expression) => Reflection()?.Where(Expression);
     public bool Any(Func<T, bool> Expression) => Reflection().Any(Expression);
     public T? FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> Expression) => Reflection().FirstOrDefault(Expression);
 }
```

Use

```
Command<People> people = new Command<People>();
var ss = people.Any(x => x.CompletedTasks == 1);
var re = people.Where(x => x.Name == x.Name).ToList();

Command<Product> product = new Command<Product>();
var res = product.Where(x => x.Name == x.Name).ToList();
var ssss = product.Any(x => x.Description == "");
```